# Typescript generic type inference not working

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

When using Typescript, I'm always wondering why those two cases are not inferred automatically?
Is there a logical reason? How would you overcome this?

```
type Test1<T> = {
  a: T,
  b: T extends string ? object : number,
};
// Error: Generic type 'Test1' requires 1 type argument(s).
// I expect Typescipt to infer T from the `a` property
const test1: Test1 = {
  a: "test1",
  b: {bb: null},
};
```

```
type Options = "option1" | "option2";
type Test2<O extends Options> = O extends "option1"
    ? {a: O, b: string}
    : {a: O};

const f = <O extends Options>(arg: Test2<O>) => {
    // Error: Property 'b' does not exist on type 'Test2<O>'.
    // I expect Typescript to infer O from the condition
    if (arg.a === "option1") arg.b;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer on your **first question**:

```js
type Test1<T> = {
  a: T,
  b: T extends string ? object : number,
};

const check = <T,>(arg: Test1<T>): Test1<T> => arg

const x = check({
  a: "test1",
  b: { bb: null },
})

const x1 = check({
  a: 2,
  b: { bb: null }, // error
})

const x2 = check({
  a: 2,
  b: 2, // ok
})
```

I have created just helper function `check` to make possible type infering

**Second question:**

```js
type TestA = {
  a: 'option1';
  b: string;
}
type TestB = {
  a: 'option2';
}

type Test = TestA | TestB

const f = (arg: Test) => {

  if (arg.a === "option1") {
    arg.b // ok
  }
}
```

Your problem seem to me related to [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24929)
Please take a look on this [comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24929#issuecomment-411225024)

Comment: Thank you for your answer captain.
Your answers work but I'm wondering if there is logical reasoning why I get those errors or if Typescript is not capable enough yet (should I create issues).

The two scenarios I gave as examples or oversimplified to demonstrate the problems. In the first case, I cannot create check functions every time I want to avoid passing a generic argument & in the second case, I actually do need the generic, union types would not work.

Comment: @MathieuUrstein I have updated the answer. https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24929#issuecomment-411225024

Comment: Thanks again, this issue is related indeed. I'll keep track of it. In the meantime, I keep this question open in case there is a Typescript update able to infer the types directly or alternative ideas on how to manage the two cases.

Comment: Sure, no problem